# Is it possible to schedule woocommerce products to go off sale after 5 purchases?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocomerce store selling memberships to study groups, the study group being the product. Each product has 2 variations, semester 1|semester 2.

Is it possible for me to sell my first 5 memberships for each product variation for free, and  update to the regular price after the first 5 are sold?

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy way: made one product with price 0, 5 in stock, another product with regular price and no stock management.

Comment: Yes, but it will have one advantage: help promoting free offer. Other way is add script to change in database term value after 5 items sold, but guessing form question, may be difficult for user33..

Comment: what you mean by unstable? need more info to help, a link?